# Reducing Ammonia Levels in Body through Bowel Movements Only

Tags: digestive-system

Can high ammonia levels in body be reduced solely through repeated bowel movements (4-5 per day), i.e., WITHOUT the use of Lactulose?

Answer (score 1):

Lactulose can decrease the blood amonia levels by either drawing some ammonia from the blood into the intestine ([MedlinePlus](https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/meds/a682338.html)) or by inhibiting ammonia production by the intestinal bacteria and hence its absorption into the blood ([Digestive Diseases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/456846), [Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/186101-overview#a7)).

By having frequent bowel movements, you could theoretically give less time to intestinal bacteria to produce ammonia from the undigested food, but, without laxatives, it may not be realistic to just decide to have 4-5 bowel movements per day.